# square root estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

Let's say we want to do an estimation using iid samples $X_i, i=1,2,3,..., N$ the following formula,
$$\hat{X}_1 = \frac{1}{N}(\sum_i\sqrt{X_i})^2$$ 
square sum of square roots.

This form also seems reasonable:

$$\hat{X}_2 = \frac{1}{N^2}(\sum_i\sqrt{X_i})^2$$

What are some nice properties that you could think of for this estimator, in addition to being a biased estimator of mean?

PS.1 What I am asking is a little different from what is conventionally being followed, I know!

PS.2 Assume that all variables can take only positive values.

PS.3 On the importance of this question:  In image processing, square root of an image, because of its noise's distribution is of special importance. Sometimes it is interesting average the squared values instead of the values themselves. I was curious to see what other people (like many statisticians at this forum) can think of, about properties of estimation using squared values; though this might come up in many different ways.

Comment: Presumably the $X_i$ are nonnegative?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the note; I corrected it .

Comment: What are you trying to estimate? That is, you say it is a biased estimator, but that depends on what is being estimated.

Comment: soakley is dead right. What characteristic of your sample do you want to estimate? mean, variance, distribution, what?

Comment: Oh, sorry; I want to estimate mean.

Comment: Then divide something somewhere by the size of the sample!

Comment: Corrected; thanks.

Comment: Daniel: Don't you think $\frac1N$ would be better placed **inside** the parenthesis defining the square?

Comment: @Did: Like this 
$\hat{X} = (\sum_i\sqrt{\frac{X_i}{N}})^2$ ?

Comment: Missed again. Check what happens when $X_i=x$ almost surely.

Comment: I see your point, probably $\frac{1}{N^2}$ is a better choice instead of $\frac{1}{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid all the square roots, define $Y=\sqrt X$. Then

$$E\hat{X}_1 = E\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_i{Y_i}\right)^2 = E\frac{1}{N} \left(\sum_i{Y_i^2}+\sum_i{Y_i\sum_{j\neq i}{Y_j}}\right)  $$

$$ = \frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_iE{X_i}\right) + E\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_i{Y_i\sum_{j\neq i}{Y_j}}\right)  $$

In the second term, the double sum translates into $N(N-1)$ pairwise products of rv's: $E(Y_iY_j)$. But that does *not* mean that you can actullay multiply the two r.v.'s - they are identically distributed, *but they are not the same r.v.*'s. So we get

$$E\hat{X}_1=EX+\frac{1}{N} N(N-1)E(Y_iY_j)= EX+(N-1)\left(E(\sqrt X)\right)^2$$

and

$$E\hat{X}_2= EX/N+(1-1/N)\left(E(\sqrt X)\right)^2$$

...meaning, that the expected value of your estimator increases with the size of the sample: not good, to put it politely. You should try divide your estimator by $N^2$, and see what happens.

Comment: @Daniel I guess the $E\hat X_2$ is the alternative estimator, where one divides by $\frac {1}{N^2}$ instead. If this is so, shouldn't the new expression be placed _after_ the last lines of the answer?